# Remove Duplicate and Count only one in a y:axis

Tags: javascript

how to remove Duplicate So that a unique label with only count of 1s is displayed.

Where My values

like

```
[
  {"y":2,"label":"Adnim"},
  {"y":2,"label":"Adnim"},
  {"y":0,"label":"Adnim"},
  {"y":0,"label":"Adnim"},
  {"y":2,"label":"Adnim2"},
  {"y":2,"label":"Adnim2"},
  {"y":2,"label":"Adnim2"},
  {"y":0,"label":"Adnim2"},
]
```

What i need the Final output is

```
 [
  { y: 2 ,  label: 'Adnim' },
 {y: 3 ,  label: 'Adnim2'},
]
```

**Ignore "0" just count "1" and Display uniquely**

FYI: label Values will be changing

Comment: Hey Shaik, did you already tried looping your array and push the distinct values into another array?

Comment: @A1rPun No i have not done

Comment: Are u not using jQuery, then extend array to add your custom function using prototype?

Comment: am using but am unable to remove duplicates and count

Comment: @AnilKumar am not getting u..:(

Comment: @AnilKumar Can u suggest the example for the same.

Comment: @AnilKumar,A1rPun am Waiting .....

Comment: Ок, so `label` values should be unique. What about `y` values, how do you choose them? Is it a number of `value`'s occurrences?

Comment: @AntonMelnikov Y value Should b the count of only "1" against that label and return the value as shown above

Comment: @A1rPun can u help me?? :(

Comment: Yeah, if you google "javascript array objects unique" you will find [this great post](https://vikasrao.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/removing-duplicates-from-a-javascript-object-array/). Instead of using dojo you can use the native `forEach`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I've understood you correctly. This program finds number of occurrence of each `label` and puts it to corresponding `y` field.

```
var list = [
  {"y":2,"label":"Adnim"},
  {"y":2,"label":"Adnim"},
  {"y":0,"label":"Adnim"},
  {"y":0,"label":"Adnim"},
  {"y":2,"label":"Adnim2"},
  {"y":2,"label":"Adnim2"},
  {"y":2,"label":"Adnim2"},
  {"y":0,"label":"Adnim2"},
]

var counters = {}
var result = [];
var label;

list.forEach(function(el){
    label = el.label;
    // Skip zero y's
    if (el.y === 0) return;

    // Increase counter values
    if (counters.hasOwnProperty(label)) {
        counters[label] += 1;
    } else {
        counters[label] = 1;
    }
});

// Convert counters object to array of objects
for (var label in counters) {
    result.push({'label': label, 'y': counters[label]});
}
```

The result is:

```
[{"label":"Adnim","y":2},{"label":"Adnim2","y":3}]
```

Comment: Was expecting the Same Can u please Re type your solution With a div

Comment: @Shaik Sorry, what do you mean?! Seriously, bro, no offence, but you should work on your English.

Comment: Sorry about the Language, i was intending to check, if you can post the same solution with a "div", reason being, when i copy paste your solution in the jsfiddle to check the output, i do not get an output. I want to inform you that the solution provided by you matches my requirement. But if i can generate an output that would be great..

Comment: Ah, now I get it! Ok, pls wait a sec.

Answer (score 1):

I thank Anton Melnikov for the below solution. Thank You Buddy.

HTML:

```
<div id="target"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
    var list = [
  {y:0,label:'Adnim'},
   {y:0,label:'Adnim'},
    {y:0,label:'Adnim'},
    {y:1,label:'Adnim'},
  {y:0,label:'Adnim2'},
 {y:0,label:'Adnim2'},
   {y:1,label:'Adnim2'},
  {y:1,label:'Adnim2'},
]

var counters = {}
var result = [];
var resultString = '';
var label;

list.forEach(function(el){
    label = el.label;
    // Skip zero y's
    if (el.y === 0) return;

    // Increase counter values
    if (counters.hasOwnProperty(label)) {
        counters[label] += 1;
    } else {
        counters[label] = 1;
    }
});

// Convert counters object to array of objects
for (var label in counters) {
    result.push({'label': label, 'y': counters[label]});
}

// Render result to the target div
console.log(result);

result = result.map(function(el){ return '{y: ' + el.y + ', label: "' + el.label + '"}' });
resultString = '[' + result.join(', ') + ']';
$('#target').html(resultString);
```

Answer (score 0):

A good choice is to use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#uniq) library, which contains the functions **unique**

Here is the way to use it to your problem:

```
var objectArray = [
  {"y":2,"label":"Adnim"},
  {"y":2,"label":"Adnim"},
  {"y":0,"label":"Adnim"},
  {"y":0,"label":"Adnim"},
  {"y":2,"label":"Adnim2"},
  {"y":2,"label":"Adnim2"},
  {"y":2,"label":"Adnim2"},
  {"y":0,"label":"Adnim2"},
],
uniquesObjects = _.uniq(objectArray, 'y');
```

Output:

```
[{y: 2, label: 'Adnim'},{y: 0, label: 'Adnim2'}]
```

Comment: How Come Admin2 value is "0"

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can use a pure javascript solution:

```
function uniques(objectArray, key){
  var uniques = {}, values = [];
  objectArray.forEach(function(obj){
    if (!uniques[obj[key]]){
      values.push(obj);
    }
    uniques[obj[key]] = obj;
  });
  return values;
}

var objectArray = [
  {"y":2,"label":"Adnim"},
  {"y":2,"label":"Adnim"},
  {"y":0,"label":"Adnim"},
  {"y":0,"label":"Adnim"},
  {"y":2,"label":"Adnim2"},
  {"y":2,"label":"Adnim2"},
  {"y":2,"label":"Adnim2"},
  {"y":0,"label":"Adnim2"},
],
uniquesObjects = uniques(objectArray, 'y');
```

Output

```
[{y: 2, label: 'Adnim'},{y: 0, label: 'Adnim2'}]
```