# Skips zero's, but display label value as Zero

Tags: javascript

Since I do not have 50 reputations, I was unable to ask my question on the same post here ([Remove Duplicate and Count only one in a y:axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30709184/remove-duplicate-and-count-only-one-in-a-yaxis/30711479#30711479)).

I am working on a similar project, everything on the post ([Remove Duplicate and Count only one in a y:axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30709184/remove-duplicate-and-count-only-one-in-a-yaxis/30711479#30711479)) looks good. The output is also perfect however, I need one extra thing added to the output.

The Present Input:

```
var list = [
  {y:0,label:'Computers'},
  {y:0,label:'Computers'},
  {y:0,label:'Computers'},
  {y:1,label:'Computers'},
  {y:0,label:'Math'},
  {y:0,label:'Math'},
  {y:1,label:'Math'},
  {y:1,label:'Math'},
]
```

What I am already getting is:

```
[{y: 1, label: "Computers"}, {y: 2, label: "Math"}]
```

This is perfect to me, this solution on the URL I mentioned, skips zero's, removes duplicates .. I need all of this, I do not need any change in these, however, if all the values of one subject are zero's then I want the output to display  a single output for zero. To make it clear below is my input and

New Input:
If all the values of 'Computers' are y: is Zero, then I want the output at least to inform me that it is all Zero.

```
var list = [
  {y:0,label:'Computers'},
  {y:0,label:'Computers'},
  {y:0,label:'Computers'},
  {y:0,label:'Computers'}, //here all the values are zero for computers

  {y:0,label:'Math'},
  {y:0,label:'Math'},
  {y:1,label:'Math'},
  {y:1,label:'Math'},
]
```

Present Output:

```
[{y: 2, label: "Math"}] //this is perfect but, with skip of zeros, I need an output like the below expected output
```

Expected Output:

```
[{y: 0, label: "Computers"}, {y: 2, label: "Math"}]
```

Comment: is Math's y = 2 because you want to sum the individual entries? or is it a typo?

Answer (score 0):

My vanilla js answer is:

EDIT: Didn't notice that the question is 1 year old :D

```js
var list = [
  {y:0,label:'Computers'},
  {y:0,label:'Computers'},
  {y:0,label:'Computers'},
  {y:1,label:'Computers'},
  {y:0,label:'Math'},
  {y:0,label:'Math'},
  {y:1,label:'Math'},
  {y:1,label:'Math'},
];

var out = []; 

var filt = {};
for (var entry of list) {
  if (!filt[entry.label]) {
    filt[entry.label] = {y: 0, label: entry.label}
  }
  
  filt[entry.label].y += entry.y;
}

for (var key in filt) {
  out.push(filt[key]);
}

// out is the list you need

document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(out);
```

Comment: you could fix your indentation

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly (you want to count the number of positive `y` values for each `label`) this should do it

```
var data = [
  {y:0,label:'Computers'},
  {y:0,label:'Computers'},
  {y:0,label:'Computers'},
  {y:0,label:'Computers'}, //here all the values are zero for computers

  {y:0,label:'Math'},
  {y:0,label:'Math'},
  {y:1,label:'Math'},
  {y:2,label:'Math'},
]

var output = data.reduce(function(acc, val){ 
    if (val.label in acc) {
        acc[val.label].y += 1 ? val.y > 0 : 0;
    } else {
        acc[val.label] = {y: 1 ? val.y > 0 : 0, label:val.label};
    }
    return acc;
}, {});

// and to make it into an array of results
var res = [];
for (var key in output) {
    res.push(output[key]);
}

// [{y:0, label:'Computers'}, {y:2, label:'Math'}]
```

If however, you care about the value of `y` and want to use their sum, a slight modification would do the trick

```
var output = data.reduce(function(acc, val){ 
    if (val.label in acc) {
        acc[val.label].y += val.y;
    } else {
        acc[val.label] = {y:val.y, label:val.label};
    }
    return acc;
}, {});

var res = [];
for (var key in output) {
    res.push(output[key]);
}

// [{y:0, label:'Computers'}, {y:3, label:'Math'}]
```

[Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is nice here I think because it has an accumulator (a variable that it remembers) and uses a function on all the elements of an array.

Using reduce, we have an accumulator object `{}` (initial value) and add to it our labels, `{'Math':{y:x, label:'Math'}, ..}` and increment their `y` values depending on our data. The last step of making it into an array is only necessary if that is the desired output format, all the results are in the `output` variable.

Looking at [Hendry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43139733/5272567)'s answer, perhaps reduce is overkill. But a fun exercise at least.